# retrieve a property from firedatabase angular

Tags: angular, firebase

i was trying to get the property name from my firebase collection user. I create a service with this function.

```
  getUserMessage(UserID: string) {
    return this.db.collection('users', ref => ref.where('uid', '==', UserID).valueChanges();
  }
```

Thats work fine becouse when I retrieve the data from another component by this way

```
getUser(UserID: string) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    const userName : User = this.chatService.getUserMessage(UserID).subscribe((data) => {
     console.log(data);
     return data;
   });
  }, 1000);
}
```

with the console.log I recive {email: "XXXX", name: "xxxx", uid="xxxx"}. But when I try to use data.name this say undefined.

Note: I was using setTimeout because when i look the console in chrome these have a print every milisecond, theres a way to make the subscribe only work by a certain time?

Comment: Why are you using `.valueChanges()` you should remove it and `setTimeout` as well.

Comment: I was using valueChanges() because I making a chatapp... so when the user change his user name i need these name change too in the chatroom. I don't know if that is the correct way

Answer (score 0):

I solve this using .map()

```
  `getUser(UserID: string) {
    this.chatService.getUserMessage(UserID).subscribe((data) => {
      this.name = data.map(a => {return a["name"];});
      return this.name;
      });
   }`
```

In other hand i have problems to show this in a  as a function {{getUser(parameter)}}. With console.log() i retrieve the name, so i think the function is ejecuted but in the label this don't appear in the html component.
example:

```
<ion-label> {{this.getUser(mensaje.user_id)}} </ion-label>
```

Comment: If for someone it's usefull. The problem was in the return statment, this must have to be after the subscribe function